# TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript

Хочу создать многомерный массив, заполненный значения двух атрибутов, чтобы вышло что-то вроде:

```
"marks": [
    [2,1],
    [1,2]
]
```

Но выпадает ошибка

> TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined

Код следующий, ошибка в данном случае в районе `marks[i] =`:

```
var marks;
var cols2 = document.querySelectorAll('.speech_gap');
    cols2.forEach(function (speech, i) {
        marks[i] = [speech.getAttribute("emotion"), speech.getAttribute("who")];
});
```

Что не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае не инициализирована переменная *marks*. Ее значение по умолчанию - *undefined*.

Поэтому при вызове `marks[i]` происходит ошибка. Для решения, достаточно инициализировать данную переменную массивом

```
var marks = [];
```

Кроме того, раз уж на основе одной коллекции нужно составить другую, лучше использовать метод [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), который специально для этого предназначен

```
var cols2 = document.querySelectorAll('.speech_gap');
var marks = Array.from(cols2).map(function (speech, i) {
        return [speech.getAttribute("emotion"), speech.getAttribute("who")];
});
```

[Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from?v=control) используется для того, чтобы получить из коллекции col2 массив, у которого есть метод map.

Comment: Большое спасибо, все идеально.